# Is there a way to bind all these elements together for changing screen sizes/zooming?

Tags: html, css, shopify, overlay

So I was tossed into a web dev position, and made a website. *gulp* I'm trying to figure out how to change the CSS for this so that all overlay elements stay in their exact places even during zooming in/out, and on all screens. https://diamondbackbranding.com/pages/whypromo is what it's supposed to look like at all times.

I've tried doing vh/vw, but the elements stay the same size and move out of position in between media breaks.  Is the solution just to do like 10 different media breaks, customizing each one?  Web Dev is only a part of my job, and not the focus, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

```css
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

.cggh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 35px;
}

.cggi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.ety {
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 35px;
}  
.ety1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.ety2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55%;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #0A4E80;
}
.wphead1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 93px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 215px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 96px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 265px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 153px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wpright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.wpad1 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 600px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.wpad2 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 660px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 35px;
}
.wpad3 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 790px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55%;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #0A4E80;
}

.relmass1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 105px;
  left: 130px;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 24%;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.relmass2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 305px;
  left: 130px;
  font-size: 29px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 27px;
}

.relmass3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 550px;
  left: 130px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.relmass4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 810px;
  left: 130px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.relcrd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 180px;
  right: 240px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.relphn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 360px;
  left: 750px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 17%;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.relhkey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 360px;
  right: 85px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.relckey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 860px;
  left: 790px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 25px;
}
.relwlt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 835px;
  right: 143px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 25px;
}

.cggleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 320px;
  left: 300px;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 8%;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.cggmid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 530px;
  left: 350px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 20px;
}
.cggright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 680px;
  right: 710px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.cggbot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 800px;
  left: 15%;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: #0A4E80;
}

.cgg53 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 270px;
  right: 150px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}

.cgg48 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  right: 77px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
  line-height: 25px;
  color: white;
}

table, td, tr {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.container1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}

.cggh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.cggi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.ety {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 5px;
}  
.ety1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.ety2 {
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55%;
  line-height: 8px;
  color: #0A4E80;
}
.wphead1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wpright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 7px;
}
.wpad1 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 15px;
}
.wpad2 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 125px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.wpad3 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 8px;
  color: #0A4E80;
}
.relmass1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 6px;
}

.relmass2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 22px;
  font-size: 6.5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 6px;
}

.relmass3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 97px;
  left: 22px;
  font-size: 6.5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 6px;
}
.relmass4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 145px;
  left: 24px;
  font-size: 6.5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 6px;
}
.relcrd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 12px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 6px;
}
.relphn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 135px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 17%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.relhkey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 61px;
  right: 13px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.relckey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 158px;
  left: 143px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.relwlt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 26px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.cggleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 55px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 9%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.cggmid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  left: 65px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.cggright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  right: 135px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.cggbot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 145px;
  left: 15%;
  font-size: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 7px;
  color: #0A4E80;
}
.cgg53 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  right: 27px;
  font-size: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 6px;
  color: white;
}
.cgg48 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 118px;
  right: 17px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
  line-height: 5px;
  color: white;
}
table, td, tr {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 481px) {
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}

.cggh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 15px;
}

.cggi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.ety {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 10px;
}  
.ety1 {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.ety2 {
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55%;
  line-height: 8px;
  color: #0A4E80;
}
.wphead1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 60%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wpright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 40%;
  line-height: 7px;
}
.wpad1 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 15px;
}
.wpad2 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 125px;
  right: 0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 10px;
}
.wpad3 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 160px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 8px;
  color: #0A4E80;
}
.relmass1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 7px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 6px;
}

.relmass2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58px;
  left: 22px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 5px;
}

.relmass3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 102px;
  left: 23px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.relmass4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 147px;
  left: 24px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 25%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.relcrd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 12px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 6px;
}
.relphn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 135px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 17%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.relhkey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 61px;
  right: 13px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.relckey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 158px;
  left: 143px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.relwlt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  right: 26px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.cggleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 55px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 9%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.cggmid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  left: 65px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.cggright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 110px;
  right: 135px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 5px;
}
.cggbot {
  position: absolute;
  top: 145px;
  left: 15%;
  font-size: 7px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 7px;
  color: #0A4E80;
}
.cgg53 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  right: 27px;
  font-size: 6px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 6px;
  color: white;
}
.cgg48 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 118px;
  right: 17px;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
  line-height: 5px;
  color: white;
}
table, td, tr {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 6px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container1"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/Blankwhite.jpg?v=1604940219" alt="WPHead" width="100%" />
<div class="wphead1">THE SUPER SIMPLE</div>
<div class="wphead2">SCIENCE</div>
<div class="wphead3">OF PROMOTIONAL</div>
<div class="wphead4">PRODUCTS.</div>
<div class="wpright">There are pretty much three basic reasons why you'd be looking to order our products: To advertise to consumers in an effective way, To show your appreciation to existing or future clients, or to show your employees just how thankful you are for the work they do. <br />No matter the reasoning, we want to give you a simple look (through science, of course) on why promo merchandise is the best way to go about doing those things.</div>
<div class="wpad1">ADVERTISING TO OTHER COMPANIES.</div>
<div class="wpad2"><i>OTHERWISE KNOWN AS THE RELATIVITY OF MASS</i></div>
<div class="wpad3">There is no debate, your business card is an important part of marketing that holds vital information for possible clients. Unfortunately, humans tend to lose small items all the time, even ones that hold extreme value. Don't let your future relationships depend solely on a modest piece of cardstock.</div>
</div>
<div class="container1"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/relativity_of_mass.gif?v=1604440786" alt="WhyPromo" style="width: 100%;" />
<div class="relmass1">A single promotional item averages <b style="color: #c25e36;">344</b> impressions per month.</div>
<div class="relmass2"><b style="color: gold;">82%</b> of people have a more favorable impression of a brand after receiving a promotional product.</div>
<div class="relmass3"><b style="color: blue;">72%</b> of consumers believe that the quality of a promotional product is directly related to the reputation of the company.</div>
<div class="relmass4">The CPI of promotional products can be as low as <b>1/10th</b> of one cent - lower than nearly any other advertising medium.</div>
<div class="relcrd"><b>Your Beautiful Business Card</b><br />Size: 2" x 3.5"<br />Weight: 0.05216 oz</div>
<div class="relphn"><b>Your customers' 1000+ dollar phone</b><br />Size: 5.95" x 2.76"<br />Weight: 6.84 oz</div>
<div class="relhkey"><b>Your customers' key to their very expensive home</b><br />Size: 1.38" x 2.76"<br />Weight: 0.246918 oz</div>
<div class="relckey"><b> Your customers' key to their very expensive car</b><br />Size: 54mm<br />Weight: 3.80 oz</div>
<div class="relwlt"><b>The thing that holds your customers' money and important personal information</b><br />Size: 3.5" x 4.5"<br />Weight: 5 oz</div>
</div>
<div class="container1"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/client_gift_giving_circle.gif?v=1604953591" alt="Client-gift-giving" width="100%" />
<div class="cggh">CLIENT GIFT-GIVING</div>
<div class="cggi">THE RELEASE OF OXYTOCIN</div>
<div class="cggleft">Client receives gift from you.</div>
<div class="cggmid">Oxytocin molecules are released in the body, creating that warm fuzzy feeling.</div>
<div class="cggright">Those feel good feelings are returned to you through repeat business.</div>
<div class="cgg53">of consumers have a more favorable opinion of an advertiser if the promo product was made in the U.S.</div>
<div class="cgg48">of consumers would like to receive promotional products more often.</div>
<div class="cggbot">(We recommend throwing in a nice,<br />handwritten note for maximum oxytocin levels)</div>
</div>
<div class="ety">EMPLOYEE THANK YOU'S.</div>
<br />
<div class="ety1">STOPPING THE SPREAD OF INFECTION</div>
<br /><center>
<div class="ety2">While the spread of germs is an obvious threat, the spread of low morale can also create an unhealthy work environment. Rethink the way you reward your employees.</div>
</center><br />
<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="33%"><b>High Five</b><br />Surface is covered in germs <br />which spread on contact.</td>
<td width="33%"><b>Pizza Party</b><br />While everyone loves pizza, <br />the effects are not long-lasting.</td>
<td width="33%"><a href="https://www.diamondbackbranding.com/collections/drinkware"><b>Branded Tumbler</b></a><br /> Made of durable material that lasts,<br /> it is very functional with their lifestyle,<br /> and can be given with the company logo.</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/employee_icons.png?v=1604957829" alt="EIcons" width="100%" />
```

Comment: the websites structure is ancient from times befor HTML 5 and CSS2. It has no responsive design in mind. WIth CSS3, you shouldnt use so much absolute positioning and espacially not sue tables for design purpose. Thats what you have CSS-Grid and Flexboxes for. IMHO it would be best not to fix it, but rewriting it with a responsive design in mind using modern solutions.

Comment: There seem to be quite a few positioning settings that are px rather than some relative unit. Also I’d go for the @tacshy solution rather than having loads of media queries. It’s not possible to cater for every potential viewport size with queries.

Comment: @tacoshy Looks like I have a lot of research to do.  I actually wrote all this code myself, learning as I went, just a few weeks ago.  We're using the Loft theme, a few apps for pricing and whatnot, and then my haphazard coding.  What do you mean by it's ancient, and also could you recommend any good resources for learning CSS-Grid and Flexboxes?

Comment: Edit to add: I have no schooling, or experience in web design before about 6 months ago when I was placed in this position, and nobody to learn from.  I may have been using the wrong resources, idk.

Comment: I see and know that it is a tough spot. What I recommend you as a start, is to learn css-grid and flexboxes. The basics can be learned in less then a week. Also use comments `HTML: <!-- Comment -->` and `CSS: /* Comment */` to comment everything and keeping order within your code. This will help you greatly and others to work with it. If you could incldue a drawing of the wanted design, we proberly could help you witht hat project.

Comment: @NoobPat .. https://css-tricks.com/ & https://getbootstrap.com/ .. really the best places to start with

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp - I also can recommend W3Schools

Comment: Thank you guys!  Gonna dig in right away.

Comment: I've deleted my previous comments because looking more closely at the site that is to be mirrored you can see that all the styling is relative, and relative to the viewport, including font-sizes. The styling also uses 'modern' CSS such as grid where that is appropriate. For some of it - the overlaying of text on an image - there has to be relative positioning of the text. Hence the code looks 'old fashioned' but what else can it do? Is there a reason you started to implement your own CSS which introduces fixed units rather than take the style from the to-be-copied site?

Comment: Good news! You don't have to rewrite it all. The code in the original website is modern already (using grid where it can) and uses relative units everywhere so resizes correctly. I've extracted the majority of what is needed and put it into an answer. You only need to do minor tweaking, e.g. choosing the correct fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to find styling that works at different viewport sizes.
The question included some initial HTML but not the styling from another site and some styling that had been applied on top.

The problem is that the styling applied in the question used fixed units in some places, but the original site uses entirely relative sizing, including for font sizes, relative to the viewport. This was necessary because, although 'modern' CSS was used where appropriate (e.g. grid),  relative positioning and sizing had to be applied where it was required to position text correctly over a couple of GIFs.

If we don't use the style element given in the question, but use the styling for the main element in the original website we get (almost) what is required - i.e. someone has already done the work of finding out where the text overlaid on the GIFs should be and it's all there relatively positioned.

Here's the whole thing. A few adjustments are needed to get padding right and I had to correct an error in the original CSS (missing ; and object-fit applied to the containing element rather than the img itself) but otherwise things seem to be in the right place and work on resizing, though you may want to think about what should actually happen at the one break point which is used here, 600px width.

```html
<main class="main-content mobile-main " style="margin-top: initial; padding-top: 0px;">

<!-- /templates/page.liquid -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
  #PageContainer {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

<div class="grid--full section__standard-spacing--even">
    <div class="rte page-text">
<style>
:root {
    --swiper-navigation-size: 44px;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
.wphead1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 5.05vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 10.8vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23.5%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 5.2vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28.5%;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 8.2vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wpright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  right: 0%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 35%;
}
.wpad1 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  right: 0%;
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.wpad2 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 74%;
  right: 0%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.wpad3 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55%;
  color: #0A4E80;
}

.relmass1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

.relmass2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 26%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.relmass3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50.8%;
  left: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 26%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.relmass4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 74%;
  left: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 26%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.relcrd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17.8%;
  right: 3.8%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.relphn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 43.3%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 17%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.relhkey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  right: .8%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 24%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.relckey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 82%;
  left: 45.5%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.relwlt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 81%;
  right: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.cggh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.cggi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
  
.cggleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 17%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 8%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.cggmid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58%;
  left: 20%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: right;
  width: 13%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
  
.cggright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73%;
  right: 41%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: right;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.cggbot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 15%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #0A4E80;
}

.cgg53 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 9%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.cgg48 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71%;
  right: 5%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: white;
}
  
  
.ety {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
}  
.ety1 {
  font-size: 1.7vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.ety2 {
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #0A4E80;
}
  

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  rgrid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid-item {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 10vw;
  rwidth: 33.33%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container1 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
}
.wphead1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 4.2vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 9vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 21%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 4.3vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wphead4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27%;
  left: 0px;
  font-size: 6.8vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  color: #c25e36;
}

.wpright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  right: 0%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 45%;
}
.wpad1 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  right: 0%;
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.wpad2 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 68%;
  right: 0%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.wpad3 {
 position: absolute;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55%;
  color: #0A4E80;
}

.relmass1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
}

.relmass2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28%;
  left: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 26%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.relmass3 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50.8%;
  left: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 26%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.relmass4 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 74%;
  left: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1.4vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 26%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.relcrd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 17.8%;
  right: 3.8%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 30%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.relphn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  left: 43.3%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 17%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.relhkey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34%;
  right: .8%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 24%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.relckey {
  position: absolute;
  top: 82%;
  left: 45.5%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.relwlt {
  position: absolute;
  top: 81%;
  right: 8.5%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.cggh {
  position: absolute;
  top: 6%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.cggi {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
  
.cggleft {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 17%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: left;
  width: 8%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.cggmid {
  position: absolute;
  top: 58%;
  left: 20%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: right;
  width: 13%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
  
.cggright {
  position: absolute;
  top: 73%;
  right: 41%;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: right;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 100%;
}

.cggbot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3%;
  left: 15%;
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 45%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #0A4E80;
}

.cgg53 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  right: 9%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.cgg48 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 71%;
  right: 5%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 18%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: white;
}
  
  
.ety {
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
}  
.ety1 {
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 100%;
}
.ety2 {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 55%;
  line-height: 100%;
  color: #0A4E80;
}
  

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid-item {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  object-fit: contain;
}
.grid-item img {
  object-fit: contain;
}
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid-item {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  object-fit: contain;/* wrong place */
}
.grid-item img {
  object-fit: contain;
}  
  
</style>
<div class="container1">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/Blankwhite.jpg?v=1604940219" alt="WPHead" width="100%">
<div class="wphead1">THE SUPER SIMPLE</div>
<div class="wphead2">SCIENCE</div>
<div class="wphead3">OF PROMOTIONAL</div>
<div class="wphead4">PRODUCTS.</div>
<div class="wpright">There are pretty much three basic reasons why you'd be looking to order our products: To advertise to consumers in an effective way, To show your appreciation to existing or future clients, or to show your employees just how thankful you are for the work they do. <br>No matter the reasoning, we want to give you a simple look (through science, of course) on why promo merchandise is the best way to go about doing those things.</div>
<div class="wpad1">ADVERTISING TO OTHER COMPANIES.</div>
<div class="wpad2"><i>OTHERWISE KNOWN AS THE RELATIVITY OF MASS</i></div>
<div class="wpad3">There is no debate, your business card is an important part of marketing that holds vital information for possible clients. Unfortunately, humans tend to lose small items all the time, even ones that hold extreme value. Don't let your future relationships depend solely on a modest piece of cardstock.</div>
</div>
<div class="container1">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/relativity_of_mass.gif?v=1604440786" alt="WhyPromo" style="width: 100%;">
<div class="relmass1">A single promotional item averages <b style="color: #c25e36;">344</b> impressions per month.</div>
<div class="relmass2">
<b style="color: gold;">82%</b> of people have a more favorable impression of a brand after receiving a promotional product.</div>
<div class="relmass3">
<b style="color: blue;">72%</b> of consumers believe that the quality of a promotional product is directly related to the reputation of the company.</div>
<div class="relmass4">The CPI of promotional products can be as low as <b>1/10th</b> of one cent - lower than nearly any other advertising medium.</div>
<div class="relcrd">
<b>Your Beautiful Business Card</b><br>Size: 2" x 3.5"<br>Weight: 0.05216 oz</div>
<div class="relphn">
<b>Your customers' 1000+ dollar phone</b><br>Size: 5.95" x 2.76"<br>Weight: 6.84 oz</div>
<div class="relhkey">
<b>Your customers' key to their very expensive home</b><br>Size: 1.38" x 2.76"<br>Weight: 0.246918 oz</div>
<div class="relckey">
<b> Your customers' key to their very expensive car</b><br>Size: 54mm<br>Weight: 3.80 oz</div>
<div class="relwlt">
<b>The thing that holds your customers' money and important personal information</b><br>Size: 3.5" x 4.5"<br>Weight: 5 oz</div>
</div>
<div class="container1">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/client_gift_giving_circle.gif?v=1604953591" alt="Client-gift-giving" width="100%">
<div class="cggh">CLIENT GIFT-GIVING</div>
<div class="cggi">THE RELEASE OF OXYTOCIN</div>
<div class="cggleft">Client receives gift from you.</div>
<div class="cggmid">Oxytocin molecules are released in the body, creating that warm fuzzy feeling.</div>
<div class="cggright">Those feel good feelings are returned to you through repeat business.</div>
<div class="cgg53">of consumers have a more favorable opinion of an advertiser if the promo product was made in the U.S.</div>
<div class="cgg48">of consumers would like to receive promotional products more often.</div>
<div class="cggbot">(We recommend throwing in a nice,<br>handwritten note for maximum oxytocin levels)</div>
</div><br><br>
      
<!-- Not attached to any card, free floating -->      

<div class="ety">EMPLOYEE THANK YOU'S.</div>
<div class="ety1">STOPPING THE SPREAD OF INFECTION</div><center>
<div class="ety2">While the spread of germs is an obvious threat, the spread of low morale can also create an unhealthy work environment. Rethink the way you reward your employees.</div>
</center><br><br>
  <div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-item"><b>High Five</b><br>Surface is covered in germs <br>which spread on contact. <br><br> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/hands_1.png?v=1606939061" height=""></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><b>Pizza Party</b><br>While everyone loves pizza, <br>the effects are not long-lasting. <br><br> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/pizza_1.png?v=1606939061"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"><a href="https://www.diamondbackbranding.com/collections/drinkware"><b>Branded Tumbler</b></a><br> Made of durable material that lasts,<br> it is very functional with their lifestyle,<br> and can be given with the company logo. <br><br>  <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0431/6184/5920/files/drinkwear_1.png?v=1606939061"></div><br>
  </div>
  </div></div>
</main>
```

Note: the original website put style elements in amongst HTML which isn't the done thing nowadays so some tidying up is needed there.

Comment: Yeah I spent about 6 hours yesterday editing everything.   It works exactly how I wanted it to, THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad it worked, the GIFs are interesting - but somewhat tricky to get the text properly aligned so I'm please someone else did it for us!